# Turn off system hotkeys/shortcuts in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, package

Hi I would to turn off system hotkeys. I cant any find package which has blocking functions or allow to block system shortcuts like windows+tab, alt+tab, windows and linux shortcuts/hotkeys. I care about that user cannot exit on my aplication to windows. I know that it can be external or manual methods like Local Group Privacy Editor or Regedit and possibly automation by scripts, but I want make as possible as easly. You guys are my last resort to avoid writing a dart package.

I tried researching pup.dev dart packages, but this package doesn't seem to be there yet

Comment: I suggest you could try to disable the Windows Key with a Keyboard Hook. You could refer to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/disabling-shortcut-keys-in-games#disable-the-windows-key-with-a-keyboard-hook